# FTP ls Command - Returns Empty File

Tags: ftp

I am trying to retrieve a list of files from a remote FTP server using the ls command. When just executing ls by itself in the command line, it lists the files. When adding a filename to the command, it returns an empty file.

My code works perfectly on several other ftp servers (likely different server config). Not sure what is going wrong.

```
ftp> Packet tracing On .
ftp> trace on
Connected to ************.
OPEN ************
220 ************ FTP server ready.
User (*****************): 
331 Password required for ********.
230 User ********* logged in.  Access restrictions apply.
ftp> CD incoming
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> Local directory now C:\csrkb\etl\files\incoming\TASK0460\txt\FTP_OBJ_LIST.
ftp> LCD C:\csrkb\etl\files\incoming\TASK0460\txt\FTP_OBJ_LIST
ftp> ls - FTP_OBJECT_LIST.TXT
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp> BYE
221-You have transferred 0 bytes in 0 files.
221-Total traffic for this session was 12603 bytes in 2 transfers.
221-Thank you for using the FTP service on ftp-out.
221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: In my case this was the problem solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/806959/ftp-upload-fails-only-for-some-files-on-centos-6-8/806961#806961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the dash after ls? The remote server is returning an empty list. I would search in the FTP server logs. Make also a network capture with Wireshark. If you have a L7 firewall you should do a capture on the server and compare the two captures.

Comment: Thanks for posting a response. No specific reason for using the dash... it is just how we did it for the other FTP servers we pull data from. For those, it works fine.   I have put in a request to the remote servers administrators to check the logs for me. (it is a shipping carrier's FTP server from which we pull event scan data files)

Comment: Can you please try without the dash? Like `ls FTP_OBJECT_LIST.TXT`. Also make sure you are using the same case as displayed by `ls` of the folder. I mean FTP_OBJECT_LIST.TXT is not the same as Ftp_oBject_lisT.txt

Comment: Run the `debug` command in ftp before to `ls` command.

Comment: I did try it before responding, and it failed altogether... with the remote server saying it could not find the file:


`ls FTP_OBJECT_LIST.TXT
    200 PORT command successful.
    550 FTP_OBJECT_LIST.TXT: No such file or directory.
    ftp> BYE
    221-You have transferred 0 bytes in 0 files.
    221-Total traffic for this session was 366 bytes in 0 transfers.
    221-Thank you for using the FTP service on ftp-out.
    221 Goodbye.`

Comment: `No such file or directory.` - Make sure that you are using the right letter case (lower vs upper/capital). If you are using Linux, try with `lftp` and use `TAB` key to do completion.

Comment: You were correct, the dash was causing the problem. I changed it to a period '.' to represent the first parameter, which  pushed the target file name to the appropriate position.

Answer (score 2):

The ls and dir commands in ftp are intended to take a remote directory as a first parameter, not a filename - doing so with a filename may or may not work, depending on the ftp server. The syntax is:

```
ls [remote-dir] [local-file]
```

- If no parameters are passed, the current directory is listed.
- If one parameter is passed, it is assumed to be a directory and is listed
- If the 2nd parameter is passed, it is a local file and the output is sent to this.
- If the 2nd parameter is omitted or is a hyphen, then the output is sent to the terminal

Having a hyphen immediately after the 'ls' portion with something else following is not a valid command, so who knows what it will do. As is specifying a filename as the first parameter. It should only be a remote directory name.

Comment: what should be listed for the [remote-dir] if the current remote directory is the same?  do I still have to specify the remote directory from the root?

Comment: @Gary - if you don't specify anything, the current directory is listed. If you specify a directory, that directory (relative to current directory) should be listed. My point is that specifying a filename will give undefined results, as it's not part of the command syntax.

Comment: right, got it. I will do some tests and post back here with the results'

Comment: I removed the dash and swapped with a '.' period. this pushed the filename (the target file to write the list to) to the appropriate parameter.